# Can I use the same number for 2 cases in old versions in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Can I use the same number for 2 cases in a switch statement in old versions in Java?

```
int rand = 3;
switch(rand)
{
    case 3: System.out.print("***");
    case 3: System.out.print("###");
    default: System.out.println("&&&");
}
```

I am using the Java version 15.0.1 and it is not working.

Comment: Hello. First thing: please don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post. Second thing: what are you trying to achieve by having two cases with same value? What is your real goal? (Maybe this is yet another case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377))

Comment: This isn't a terrible question, and it wouldn't have been closed if you had included code as txt instead of an image, and if you had been specific about the version of Java.

Comment: This was never allowed. Even the [first version of the JLS](http://web.archive.org/web/20041205165907/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/14.doc.html#35518) states: _No two of the case constant expressions associated with a switch statement may have the same value._ And the reason is simple: which of the to cases should be executed if `rand` has a value of 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible as switch needs a single option for a particular input. You can either use one option like below.

```
int rand = 3;
switch(rand)
{
    case 3: System.out.print("***");
    default: System.out.println("&&&");
}
```

or concatenate both together like below

```
int rand = 3;
switch(rand)
{
    case 3: System.out.print("***###");
    default: System.out.println("&&&");
}
```